# Pyplot Not Displaying My Graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to graph the [recaman sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGC5TdIiT9U) as a scatter plot and as far as I can tell my script is setup correctly. Also I'm pretty sure its not the back-end because I can run scripts like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

and it works fine. Here's what my code looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
while(True):
    try:
        itterations = int(input("Itterations: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        os.system("cls")
def recaman(n):
    arr = [0] * n
    arr[0] = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        curr = arr[i-1] - i
        for j in range(0, i):
            if ((arr[j] == curr) or curr < 0):
                curr = arr[i-1] + i
                break
        arr[i] = curr
    return(arr)
def genX(n):
    x = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        i += 1
        x.append(i)
    return(x)
xaxis = genX(itterations)
yaxis = recaman(itterations)
for i in range (0,itterations):
    plt.plot(xaxis[i],yaxis[i])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of plotting individual invisible points in the loop, plot the whole curve with `plt.plot(xaxis,yaxis)` or (better) `plt.scatter(xaxis,yaxis)`.

If you prefer to plot the individual points, at least make them visible:

```
for i in range (0,itterations):
    plt.plot(xaxis[i],yaxis[i],"o")
plt.show()
```